# Google Cloud DNS giving 404 on top level domain

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-dns

I'm using Google Cloud DNS and Google App Engine Standard to configure an application.

Currently, I configured the DNS like this

```
mydomain.com.   A   300 
216.239.32.21
216.239.34.21
216.239.36.21
216.239.38.21

mydomain.com.   AAAA    300 
2001:4860:4802:32::15
2001:4860:4802:34::15
2001:4860:4802:36::15
2001:4860:4802:38::15

mydomain.com.   MX  216000  
1 aspmx.l.google.com.
5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.

mydomain.com.   NS  21600   
ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-c3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-c4.googledomains.com.

mydomain.com.   SOA 21600   
ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300

@.mydomain.com. A   300 
216.239.32.21
216.239.34.21
216.239.36.21
216.239.38.21

api.mydomain.com.   CNAME   300 
ghs.googlehosted.com.

stage.mydomain.com. CNAME   300 
ghs.googlehosted.com.

api.stage.mydomain.com. CNAME   300 
ghs.googlehosted.com.

www.stage.mydomain.com. CNAME   300 
ghs.googlehosted.com.

www.mydomain.com.   CNAME   300 
ghs.googlehosted.com.
```

So that I configured an stage environment using these domains and it is working so far.

- api.stage.mydomain.com
- stage.mydomain.com / www.stage.mydomain.com

I recently added the configuration for production with these domains

- api.mydomain.com
- mydomain.com / www.mydomain.com

And it is working so far except that mydomain.com is returning 404 http status from Google:

```
404. That’s an error.

The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

Does anyone has encountered this problem before? How can it be solved so that mydomain.com starts working?

Comment: What do you mean by "mydomain.com is returning 404 http status from Google"? Exactly what tool are you running to produce this response?

Comment: The domain is revamos.com.ar. I'm using the browser to get the response

Comment: So is there a web server running on the four servers that you have A records for (216.239.32.21 216.239.34.21 216.239.36.21 216.239.38.21)? It appears not. This does not look like a DNS problem as such.

Comment: I have inspected your DNS config for your domain and I'm seeing that it's currently pointing to Cloudflare DNS. Could you please confirm? I also see that revamos.com.ar is not working but www.revamos.com.ar does resolve to the webpage.

Comment: @KatieSinatra is right and the current DNS setup is quite different from your question. It seems that the servers you originally pointed the A record at were not expecting to serve your domain. This is probably an account issue rather than a DNS issue.

Comment: DNS servers do not return 404 errors. This is an HTTP response coming from a web server or similar software.

Comment: Most of the config is automatically given by google when the DNS was created in GCP. Found the solution, going to post it here.